# Why doesn't Jest configuration defined by 'testMatch' option match any of my test files within my project?

Tags: jestjs

This is how my Jest config file looks:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  roots: ['<rootDir>'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'server'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: './tsconfig.test.json',
    },
  },
  watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
  testMatch: ['/**/*.test.(ts|tsx)'],
  globalSetup: './global-setup.js',
};
```

and this is the output I get when I run `jest -c jest.config.js` in the project's root directory:

```
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In C:\Users\xxx\Documents\xxx\xxx\xxx
  432 files checked.
  testMatch: /**/*.test.(ts|tsx) - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 432 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
```

I had a feeling this might be related to different path separators on Windows and Linux. I'm running on Windows. So I tried changing the `testMatch` to `['\\**\\*.test.(ts|tsx)']` in `jest.config.js`. That did not resolve my issue.

I have 2 NPM scripts defined inside my `package.json` that produce the same output as above:

```
"lint-and-test": "npm run lint && npm run test"
"test": "jest --coverage --verbose"
```

Comment: I have Jest version 28.1.3 installed globally on my local setup.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a known issue for a while with Jest. See the Issue titled [testMatch on Windows #7914](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7914) for more context.

In windows default slash for file paths look like `one\two\three\file.test.ts`, but Jest does not seem to internally convert `\\`(escaped Windows style) or `/`(Unix style) path separators correctly thereby resulting in not picking up any of the test files.